# Why does "WebRTC Screen sharing" is not streaming when using different computers?

Tags: javascript, java, html, websocket, webrtc

I am developing a web application, like an online classroom in which I want to share the screen of a browser from a computer and view it in another. I am getting an error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error" in chrome when I tried to share the screen from a computer and view it on another computer.

I am using **WebRTC** for this and **WebSocket** for signaling. At the backend, java jersey would be doing the searching & forwarding of the request to the appropriate clients. I can share the screen from one browser window and view it in another on the same machine. But when I'm using different computers I get this error. When I debug the RTCPeerConnection object, it shows that the property connectionState as failed and iceConnectionState as disconnected.

Javascript: Request to share the screen

```
 var urlS = [];
 var config = {iceServers: urlS}; 
 var $source = $('#monitor-src');
 $scope.context.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
 $scope.context.peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) 
     {
         console.log(event)
         if (event.candidate) 
         {
         var json = 
          {
            type:event.type,
            label:event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id:event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate:event.candidate
          }
          WebSocket.send({desc:json,usrId:$scope.context.me.id},$scope)
         } 
         else 
         {
         console.error("Failed to create ice candidate")
         }
    };
try
    {
        $scope.context.peerConnection.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: true,offerToReceiveVideo: true}).then(function(offer) 
            {
            return $scope.context.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        }).then(function() 
            {
            WebSocket.send({desc:$scope.context.peerConnection.localDescription,callee:mentee.id,caller:$scope.context.me.id,usrId:$scope.context.me.id},$scope)
            });
     }
     catch(error)
     {
         console.error("onnegotiationneeded-"+error)
     }
    $scope.context.peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = function()
    {
        console.error("onnegotiationneeded")
    };
    try
    {
        console.log($scope.context.peerConnection);
        $scope.context.peerConnection.ontrack = function(event) 
        {
        console.log("ontrack:"+event.streams.length)
        $source.parent()[0].srcObject= event.streams[0];        
        };

       $scope.context.peerConnection.onaddstream = function(event) 
       {
         console.log("onaddstream:"+event.stream)
         $source.parent()[0].srcObject = event.stream;
       };

    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.error(error)
    }
```

Javascript:WebSocket Handling of the request and sending response

```
$rootScope.socket.onMessage(function(message)
    {
        data = angular.fromJson(message.data);
        if(data.type == 'offer')
        {
        var stream = null;
        //var urlS = [{urls: 'stun:192.168.1.16:8443'}];
        var urlS = [];
        var config = {iceServers: urlS};
        scope.context.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        scope.context.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(data).then(function(){
            return navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true,audio: true});
        }).then(function(stream){
            console.log(scope.context.peerConnection)
             scope.context.peerConnection.addStream(stream);
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track)
                    {
             //var rtpSender = 
            });
            scope.context.peerConnection.createAnswer().then(function(answer){
                return scope.context.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer)
            }).then(function()
            {
                send({desc:scope.context.peerConnection.localDescription,usrId:scope.context.me.id},scope)
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.error(error)});
        })
        }
        else if(data.type == 'answer')
        {
        scope.context.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(data);

        }
        else if(data.type == 'icecandidate')
        {
        console.log("icecandidate:"+angular.toJson(data))
              var promise = scope.context.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.candidate).then(function success(){
                 console.log("ice success")
                 }).catch(function error(err)
                 {
                console.log(err);
                 });
        }
    });
    };
```

The ontrack and onaddstream events are triggered when a stream is added to the peer connection. But I get nothing on the requested peer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JavaScript expert but your `urlS` array seems to be empty. Try to add both `Turn` and `Stun` servers in your `urlS`.

For more info take a look [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/)

Comment: I have read that if the peers are on the same network then we don't have to use a stun or turn server. But I had already tried using some stun servers. but still not working

Comment: Unfortunately no.